# Spark pivot-ing for large number of distinct values

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a 5GB csv file, with the following columns:

> ColA ColB Date Value

There are aprox. 11k unique ColA values, and about 400 unique ColB values.

I am trying to pivot the table, using Spark, so I get to the following structure:

```
ColA Date ColB_1  ColB_2  ColB_3  .. ColB_n
          Value_1 Value_2 Value_3 .. Val_n
```

I am trying to achieve this by doing:

```
dataFrame.groupBy("ColA", "Date").pivot("ColB").agg(first("Value"))
```

The jobs runs quite slow on a 2 node cluster with 8G, 4 cores each with dynamic allocation on - finishing in a few hours only. I am trying to see if it can be optimised in any way. I have read [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/09/reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-apache-spark.html) where they say :

> For the best performance, specify the distinct values of your pivot column (if you know them)

Would this be an option - to fetch the distinct values of colB and feed then to the next transformation? Is there any other way such a job can be optimised?

Looking at the nodes, I see CPU running quite high for all the tasks involved with those transformations - is pivot-ing supposed to be quite a CPU intensive operation? Also, Shuffle Spill(Memory) gets to over 11GB - is this something to worry about as well?

Comment: I am trying to solve exactly similar use case. Please let me know if you have found any optimization technique for this.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?